# Use Record Number and Heading Names to sort rows to columns, skipping blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

Sample data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit

I have sample data that looks like this:
[image]

I want the result to look like this:
[image]

1. I need one formula that uses the RED number (e.g "J1") to pull data from that record number on the table (not row number)
2. I need to pull the information by Heading name (not Column Letter);
3. I need to skip blank cells.

I have tried a number of things, but I'm just not good enough at Google Sheets coding. But I did get this far, pulling information by heading name:

=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A$1:$AW,MATCH(J1,'Sheet 1'!$A$1:$A,false),MATCH("FIRST",'Sheet 1'!$A$1:$AW$1,false))

Yet I can't figure out how to stack this for multiple cells and then to skip cells that are blank.

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:google-sheets] tag, which says : *Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(filter(choosecols($B5:$G,xmatch({"FIRST","SPOUSE","CELL","EMAIL"},$B4:$G4)),$A5:$A=J1),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Rock star status - Thank you